# CommandButton to add from listbox to sheet

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, commandbutton

hello i search a lot of information in internet but i can not get it work .I tray to  add the search results from listbox in a sheet number  the sheet name is (Tabelle1 ) listbox name is (lsbWarenausgang) and the CommandButton name is (CommandButton3)

Comment: please share your code attmepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want pass the value to the cell C1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("C1").Value = lsbWarenausgang.Value

End Sub
```

For multi-columns ListBox:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
With Me.lsbWarenausgang
   For k = 0 To .ListCount - 1
      If .Selected(k) = True Then
      For i = 1 To 5
         Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 1) = Me.lsbWarenausgang.List(k, i - 1)
       Next i
      End If
   Next k
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thets work but thets add just 1 of columns

Comment: With multi-columns you must to iterate de List checking the `.Selected ` property and if True get the .List(nRow, nCol) element.

Comment: @d00nn12345 It's an etiquette norm in StackOverflow to clicking in the **checking simbol** if the answer solves your problem.

Comment: thx a lot juyt i was checking it if it work what I need to change to a horizontal load. because the data load everything into vertical